# Is a sustained ranged or area attack, still a ranged / area attack on subsequent rounds?

Tags: dnd-4e, spells

Is a sustained ranged or area attack, still a ranged / area attack on subsequent rounds?

A player is asking whether the 'Shield of Deflection' [[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=item&id=2464)] would work against the effects of a sustained range or area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the power and what is being sustained.

If say the power was Witch's bolt and was being sustained, then sure it would grant the resistance.

However, most powers are zone sustains and in this case the damage is coming form the *zone* not an area or ranged attack.

Comment: Yeah, that was my reading of the powers the player has quizzed about, but always good to get a second opinion